# expandafter and csname

Tags: xetex, expansion, arguments, csname

I was recently looking for the creation of commands that use the name of another command and I recently discovered \expandafter and \csname instructions. I manage to create simple one using these instructions but I have problems for more complex commands.

Here is a minimal example of my code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\DeclareCentredMathEtype}[2]
{
    \DeclareMathOperator*{#1}
    {
        \begin{minipage}{\widthof{\begin{huge}#2\end{huge}}}\begin{huge}#2\end{huge}\end{minipage}
    }
}

\newcommand{\DisplayEtype}[1] 
{
    \expandafter\let\csname  old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m o m}{\IfValueTF{##2}{\underset{\substack{##1}}{\overset{##2}{\csname old#1\endcsname}} ##3 }{\underset{\substack{##1}}{\csname old#1\endcsname}{##3}}}
}

\DeclareCentredMathEtype{\test}{A}
\DisplayEtype{test}
\DisplayEtype{sum}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\oldtest_{k=0}^{3}{f(k)}$
$\displaystyle\sum{k=0}[3]{f(k)}$
%$\displaystyle\test{k=0}[3]{f(k)}$
\end{document}
```

In this code, \DisplayEtype is not working correctly. For \sum, it creates \oldsum and redefine \sum without troubles (\sum is redefine as a sum with range indice and exposant). However, in the case of \test, it creates a fatal error (the last commented line).

I think it is because of my \expandafter use here. 
I have been searching a related topic but so far, I have not found any solution.

Could you tell me what I am missing?

Thank you for your help.

PS : By the way, do you know a simple rule to know where to use \expandafter instruction ?

Comment: apart from the expandafter question beware white space at ends of lines you have lots of missing `%`

Comment: unrelated to the expandafter question but `\begin{minipage}{\widthof{\begin{huge}#2\end{huge}}}\begin{huge}#2\end{huge}\end{minipage}` is a rather complicated way of getting a huge text,  `\vcenter{\hbox{\huge #2}}` would produce a centred huge text without setting it twice

Answer (score 4):

If you add `\show` you see

```
> \oldtest=macro:
->\protect \test
```

so because `test` was originally a robust macro defined as

```
\def\test{\protect\test_}
```

(but with a space not a `_` )  then your `\let` did not save the real underlying meaning  and the `test_` macro gets used in the wrong place in the redefinition.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem with your explanation @DavidCarlisle, but I am not able to correct it because I'm a beginner with the \expandafter synthax. What is the correct way to redefine \test well in this precise case ?